# Meaning of "%" operation in C# for the numeric type double

Tags: c#, modulo

Recently I discovered that C#'s operator `%` is applicable to double. Tried some things out, and after all came up with this test:

```
class Program
{
    static void test(double a, double b)
    {
        if (a % b != a - b * Math.Truncate(a / b))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + ", " + b);
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        test(2.5, 7);
        test(-6.7, -3);
        test(8.7, 4);
        //...
    }
}
```

Everything in this test works.
Is `a % b` always equivalent to `a - b*Math.Round(a/b)`? If not, please explain to me how this operator really works.

EDIT: Answering to James L, **I understand that this is a modulo operator and everything. I'm curious only about how it works with double**, integers I understand.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Did some more testing. As it turned out, a % b is not always equivalent to a - b*Math.Truncate(a/b). For example, it's not for 1.0 and 0.1.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The modulus operator works on floating point values in the same way as it does for integers. So consider a simple example:

```
4.5 % 2.1
```

Now, 4.5/2.1 is approximately equal to 2.142857

So, the integer part of the division is 2. Subtract 2*2.1 from 4.5 and you have the remainer, 0.3.

Of course, this process is subject to floating point representability issues so beware – you may see unexpected results. For example, see this question asked here on Stack Overflow: [Floating Point Arithmetic - Modulo Operator on Double Type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925223/floating-point-arithmetic-modulo-operator-on-double-type)

---

> Is a % b always equivalent to a - b*Math.Round(a/b)?

No it is not. Here is a simple counter example:

```
static double f(double a, double b)
{
    return a - b * Math.Round(a / b);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(1.9 % 1.0);
    Console.WriteLine(f(1.9, 1.0));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

As to the precise details of how the modulus operator is specified you need to refer to the C# specification – [earlNameless's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105708) gives you a link to that.

It is my understanding that `a % b` is essentially equivalent, modulo floating point precision, to `a - b*Math.Truncate(a/b)`.

Comment: So basically a % b is always equivalent to a - b*Math.Round(a/b)?

Comment: No it is not. Replace Round with Trunc and you should be there, certainly for positive `a` and `b`.

Comment: Just to be sure, then a % b always equals a - b * Math.Truncate(a / b)?

Comment: When `a` and `b` are positive that is certainly true. I suspect that it is true for all cases, but I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: And the downvote is because of what exactly? I want to get this right.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about... I didn't downvote you answer.

Comment: @Sergey The question is addressed at whoever did downvote. I don't know who but it would naturally be odd for you to accept answer and downvote!! If I did make a mistake I'd just like to know so I can fix it.

Comment: `a % b` is not equal to `a - b * Math.Truncate(a / b)` for the values a = 1024.0 and b = 25.6.

Comment: @JLRishe Well, surely that's due to floating point representability?

Comment: Most likely. Just thought those tuning in might like to know because there was a recent [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42005119/c-sharp-modulo-function-on-double#comment71190235_42005119) about that pair of numbers.

Answer (score 5):

From [C# Language Specifications](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf?page=200) page 200:

**Floating-point remainder:**

```
float operator %(float x, float y); 
double operator %(double x, double y);
```

The following table lists the results of all possible combinations of nonzero finite values, zeros, infinities, and NaN’s. In the table, x and y are positive finite values. z is the result of x % y and is computed as x – n * y, rounded to the nearest representable value, where n is the largest integer that is less than or equal to x / y. This method of computing the remainder is analogous to that used for integer operands, but differs from the [IEC 60559](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) definition (in which n is the integer closest to x / y).

Answer (score 2):

From [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/0w4e0fzs%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) :

> The modulus operator (%) computes the remainder after dividing its
>   first operand by its second. All numeric types have predefined modulus
>   operators.

And

> Note the round-off errors associated with the double type.

Answer (score 2):

Searching with the phrase "modulo floating point c#" brings up quite a few entries in Stack Overflow, most of them explaining nicely how floating point precision complicates things. I did not recognize any suggestion for a simple practical way to handle that. What I came up with for my own purposes is the following modulo function:

```
public static double modulo( double a, double b, double num_sig_digits = 14 )
{
   double  int_closest_to_ratio
         , abs_val_of_residue
         ;

   if ( double.IsNaN( a )
      || double.IsNaN( b )
      || 0 == b
      )
   {
      throw new Exception( "function modulo called with a or b == NaN or b == 0" );
   }

   if ( b == Math.Floor( b ) )
   {
      return (a % b);
   }
   else
   {
      int_closest_to_ratio = Math.Round( a / b );
      abs_val_of_residue = Math.Abs( a - int_closest_to_ratio * b );
      if ( abs_val_of_residue < Math.Pow( 10.0, -num_sig_digits ) )
      {
         return 0.0;
      }
      else
      {
         return abs_val_of_residue * Math.Sign( a );
      }
   }
}
```

Following are some sample results:

modulo( 0.5, 0.1, 17 ) = 0

modulo( 0.5, -0.1, 16 ) = 0

modulo( -0.5, 0.1, 15 ) = 0

modulo( -0.5, -0.1, 14 ) = 0

modulo( 0.52, 0.1, 16 ) = 0.02

modulo( 0.53, -0.1, 15 ) = 0.03

modulo( -0.54, 0.1, 14 ) = -0.04

modulo( -0.55, -0.1, 13 ) = -0.05

modulo( 2.5, 1.01, 17 ) = 0.48

modulo( 2.5, -1.01, 16 ) = 0.48

modulo( -2.5, 1.01, 15 ) = -0.48

modulo( -2.5, -1.01, 14 ) = -0.48

modulo( 0.599999999999977, 0.1, 16 ) = 2.35367281220533E-14

modulo( 0.599999999999977, 0.1, 15 ) = 2.35367281220533E-14

modulo( 0.599999999999977, 0.1, 14 ) = 2.35367281220533E-14

modulo( 0.599999999999977, 0.1, 13 ) = 0

modulo( 0.599999999999977, 0.1, 12 ) = 0