# C# one number before floating point

Tags: c#

I need to somehow get one number before floating point and value after that floating point. Example:

Before: 21**2.12345**; 
After: **2.12345**

Any Ideas?

Comment: I do not know the C# API, but how about converting the number to a String, then create a substring with the needed numbers and parse it to a double again?

Comment: you can convert it to string and than use substring method combined by indexOf method.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you have:

```
decimal x = 212.12345m;
```

you can use the [modulo operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx):

```
decimal result = x % 10;
```

Note that the number should be represented as a [decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) if you care about the accurate value.

See also: [Meaning of "%" operation in C# for the numeric type double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105613/meaning-of-operation-in-c-sharp-for-the-numric-type-double)

Comment: Although if the exact decimal digits are important, the OP should consider using `decimal` rather than `double`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Good point! the question mentions floating point, I'm not sure what that means for the OP. Either way, `%` should work.

Comment: He is removing two digits 12 before decimal point as 212.12345 need to be 2.12345, How modulus operator would do that?

Comment: @Adil - The assumption here is `1234.5` -> `4.5`, not `1.5`. This is marked by the OP using bold text: "21 **2.12345**", though I agree the question is very poorly written.

Comment: I misunderstood that.

Comment: He needs to write a parser to chop off the numbers 2 places before the ".".

Comment: @ZeroPhase - Isn't that another *assumption*? We don't *know* whether the OP has a string or a numeric value. Either way, if the OP is doing an arithmetic operation, they can parse the string - if this is a number, you don't need to parse it. If this is a string, you can easily search for `.` and take a substring.

Answer (score 0):

my approach was to find the number  210, and substract it....
will work for any number as well as smaller then 10.

```
double f1 = 233.1234;
double f2 = f1 - (((int)f1 / 10) * 10);
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? This will output `2.125`. Float is not very precise. If you will change to double, you also will not get precise result: `2.12345000001369`.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky you are right, float isn't too percise, double is better, but is there a way to overcome floating point inacuracies?

Comment: Yes, there is a way - use `decimal` type

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
double x = 1; 
var y = x/10; 
var z = (y % (Math.Floor(y))) * 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
public double GetFirst(double a)
{
    double b = a / 10.0;
    return (b - (int)b) * 10.0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
string num = "15464612.12345";
string t = num.Split('.')[0];
num = t[t.Length-1].ToString() + "." + num.Split('.')[1];
```

Comment: wont work in many situations like: 
`num = 123845` or `regional settings set numbers to exponent representation 1.546461212345e7` or alternativly `regional use comma instead of dot like 15464612,12345`