# Mod operator in C#

Tags: c#, rsa, modulo

Is there a mod operator in C# for RSA algorithm? I've been using % as I thought this could be used as mod, but the answers I get for for c and m are not correct,  so I've realised % doesn't work.

```
      double e = 13;
      double d; //decryption

      double de = 7; 

      d = ((de * euiler) + 1) / e;

      double message = 25;
      double c = Pow(message, e) % n;
      double m = Pow(c, d) % n;
```

Comment: why not just use the `RSACryptoServiceProvider` class that's already there?

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082917/mod-of-negative-number-is-melting-my-brain) help you? `%` in C# is the remainder operation and not modulus.

Comment: We are missing the eulier value,  but maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8105613/meaning-of-operation-in-c-sharp-for-the-numeric-type-double helps

Comment: Maybe you need the [`Math.IEEERemainder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ieeeremainder?view=netframework-4.8) operation?

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen an implementation of RSA using floating-point values.  Every implementation I've seen uses `BigInteger` or at least `long`.

Comment: What is `euiler`? (Maybe 0.5772156649?). What is `n`? What is the expected result? What is the actual result?

Comment: @Rubikted [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) `modulo` is ambiguous for negative numbers and different languages follow different rules. Your code doesn't use negative numbers though. It *does* use imprecise floating point operations, specifically operations that are susceptible to scaling errors, not just the common precision errors. Errors like this *weaken* encryption and are used to break encrypted messages. That's why you *shouldn't* try to implement your own cryptography algorithms

Comment: @Rubikted in any case, encryption algorithms don't use floating point numbers. Floating point algorithms take the errors into consideration and go to extra lengths to produce *reproducible* results, even if this means they'll have a predetermined error . If you check eg Intel's MKL library you'll find [articles about reproducibility](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-macos-developer-guide-obtaining-numerically-reproducible-results), or descriptions of the errors introduced by different algorithm implementatios

Comment: For learning purposes this is fine but please don't use your own cryptography algorithms in production.

Comment: @Rubikted So `m=Pow(c,d)` e.g `m=Pow(2561,4549)` is `Infinity`. And why do you thisnk `c` must be 2490? P.S. I'll upvote this question, because I think type specific questions are pretty usefull.

Answer (score 5):

The confusion lies in `double` Type.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/0w4e0fzs(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN):

> The modulus operator (%) computes the remainder after dividing its first operand by its second. All numeric types have predefined modulus
>   operators.
>
> Note the round-off errors associated with the double type.

Answer (score -4):

the % is a remainder. You might want to make a static function that uses the % to make a modulo operation.

Comment: [Remainder Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-). The Microsoft docs don't call it the modulo operator (because it isn't).