# Why 2.0 % 0.1 gives 0.09999999 on debugging How to make the solution if i have to do solution if(doubleVar ==0)

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, var

I am trying to find out modulo in c# as i know remainder is obtained on doing `a modulo b= remainder` so here `a%b=remainder`  the same i tried to do like this:

```
 var distanceFactor = slider.Value % distance;
```

But the value on debugging of `slider.Value= 2.0` and `distance =0.1` and `distanceFactor` i found surprisingly is `0.0999999999..` and i was expecting it to be `0`.

Is it due to `var` ? what could be the reason for this non zero value.?
And how to do the solution of this problem ? because on rounding of this 0.0999999999 becomes 0.1 ans my control never go in condition `if(distanceFactor==0)` (and roundoff is also necessary in current situation).Is there any alternative to achieve it ?

Comment: _Is it due to var ?_ NO! This how floating-point number works.

Comment: @SonerGönül sorry could you please explain a bit more ? shouldnt it be 0.0 ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925223/floating-point-arithmetic-modulo-operator-on-double-type

Comment: @user1251683 please see th edited question it conntains 2 parts please let meknow the solution also .

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. A floating point number does not exactly represent a decimal number like the type `decimal` would do. Look at [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html) for a detailed description.

Comment: But how to do the solution of this problem ? because on rounding of this 0.0999999999 becomes 0.1 ans my control never go in condition if(distanceFactor==0)

Comment: thanks but please also let me know how to make the solution of problem in the current situation.

Comment: You should **not** do `if(distanceFactor==0)`, **period**. You should do something like this: `if(Math.Abs(distanceFactor-0) < 0.000001)` where `-0` can be removed, but `0` here is the original `0` from your original expression, so if you compare to something else, it goes there, and `0.000001` is a *small enough* value that will be enough to catch the values you're interested in.