# How to convert an Integer or Float values into Degrees?

Tags: c#, math, trigonometry, angle

For example:

```
float AngleAddition(float value)
{
   float angle = value + 90;
   return angle;  
 }
```

If the value passed is 340 to this method it should return a float of value 70 which is in degree. Since 340 + 90 = 360 + 70  (360 is nothing but 0 in degrees).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: What is the expected behaviour for *negative* angles? what would the result be if it was -180  + 90 ?

Comment: @MarcGravell's point is important, particularly for negative non-integral types where modulo *may* do something unexpected.

Comment: it would be -90 which is exactly I need ! The only thing is that, it should not be greater than +360 or -360

Comment: -360 to +360 introduces degeneracy; for example, -90 is the same as +270. Are you sure you need this?

Comment: @Bathsheba A just question ! For now am passing only positive values, may be it would be a problem in future implementation

Answer (score 2):

You should use the modulo operator with the 360 value.

```
public float AngleAddition(float angle, float value)
{
   return (angle + value)%360;  
}
```

The modulo operator should work for `float` or `double`, just keep in mind the limitations of numeric representation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925223/floating-point-arithmetic-modulo-operator-on-double-type) for a case study.

Answer (score 0):

```
private float AngleAddition(float value)
{
   return (value + 90) % 360;  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure either, but *are you confident* this works for floating point types? Not sure about the value 90 either but that seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: @Bathsheba Just tested with sample input OP provided, If not cast it to integer it will work. 90 is one quarter of 360 degree. That's what OP asks.

Comment: You ought to verify 360.1 for example.

Comment: @Bathsheba Just tested, it returns `0.1000061`. Rounding it as integer depends upon op's need.

Comment: Why %90? You would not expect 180+90 to result in zero. You would expect 270. Also: what happened to the "addition" part of the question?

Comment: @MarcGravell Question asks for input `340` should return `70`. If you ask as degrees It would still be `340` isn't it?

Comment: no, the OP asks that 340 **plus 90**, i.e. 430 - results in 70. The kep point being that 360 is a complete circle, so 430 degrees is the same direction as 70 degrees.

Comment: I just understand the question. Thanks for making it clear. I'll update my answer.