# How to get modulo from floats?

Tags: javascript

I have two inputs #input_a and #input_b with decimal:

```
<input id="input_a" name="input_a" step="any" type="number">
<input id="input_b" name="input_b" step="any" type="number">

<a href="javascript:checkForm();">Save</a>
```

and js:

```
function checkForm(i){
    var a = $('input#input_a').val().replace(',','.');
    var b = $('input#input_b').val().replace(',','.');
    var send = true;

    if(parseFloat(a) % parseFloat(b) != 0){
        $('#formerror).html('Invalid');
        send = false;
    }

    if(send==true) {
        $('#form').submit();
    }
}
```

but for example for values input_a = 2, input_b = 0.1

```
parseFloat(a) % parseFloat(b) = 0.09999999999
```

and give me an error. How to do it this well?

Comment: You're going to have to describe more about what you're trying to accomplish, because it's not clear at all. Why are you performing a `%` operation in the first place?

Comment: Which is the "error"? That result ( 0.09...9 ) ?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript uses [binary floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) representations of numbers. As a result of this, the internal representation `0.1` is only an approximation of the decimal value. This is the same reason that `0.1 + 0.2` yields `0.30000000000000004`.

So while 2 is divisible by 0.1, it *isn't* perfectly divisible by the runtime's internal approximation of `0.1`.

One way around this would be to check for *very close* divisors, rather than *perfect* divisors:

```
// note +value is shorthand for parseFloat(value)
var a = +$('input#input_a').val().replace(',','.'), 
    b = +$('input#input_b').val().replace(',','.'),
    epsilon = 1e-10, // some very small value
    mod = a % b;

if(mod < epsilon || b - mod < epsilon){
    $('#form').submit();
} else {
    $('#formerror).html('Invalid');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Check out this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2925496/2956903

It actually is for C# but I think the same could apply to your example.

*So the answer is:*

#### There is no error. Floating point arithmetic just does not offer more precision.